# Wrong number of rows and columns in printed pattern

Tags: java

My task is to create a program that shows a pattern using parameters (rows and columns ) the number of rows and columns must be read from keyboard and I must use 2 loops. I tried it and it is somehow right but I don't want to have increment in for loop but whenever I remove it I don't get desired pattern

For example if I enter rows:2 and column:4 the pattern would be with 3 rows and 5 columns

I need a pattern like this for rows:2 and columns:4 like

```
XXXX
XXXX
```

Would someone help me to tell where the problem is?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
    int rows = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
    int columns = in.nextInt();

    Pattern(rows, columns);
}
public static void Pattern (int rows, int columns) {
    for ( int i=0; i <= rows ;i++) {
        for ( int a=0; a<= columns ;a++) {
            System.out.print("X");
            // only print to have pattern on same row
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `<=` with `<`, or start from `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: @Pshemo That's the correct answer - you might as well post it as one, rather than as a comment.

Comment: @CraigOtis Some people don't post the answers as an answer because it's something relatively straight forward.

Comment: if i change <= to < and use 1 instead of 0 it shows only 1 X (i have entered rows:2 and column:2 ) but still it showed one X

Comment: @Rim_Jhim Only do one or the other, not both. Use `<=` and start at `1`, or use `<` and start at `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in:

```
for ( int i=0; i <= rows ;i++) {
    for ( int a=0; a<= columns ;a++) {
```

The issue is that `i` starts at `0` and goes all the way to `rows` (same with `a` and `columns`)

The way to fix this is to simply change:

```
int i=0
```

to

```
int i=1
```

And do the same for a.

This is known as an "Off by one error" and is common enough to have it's own name. (you're not alone :) )

You could also change both of the `<=` to just `<` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `<=` with `<`, or start from `1` instead of `0`.

Take a look at loop like this one `for (int i = 0; i<=3; i++){ }`

1. `i=0`, `i<=3` (`0<=3` true) lets continue and increment i after it to 1
2. `i=0`, `i<=3` (`1<=3` true) lets continue and increment i after it to 2
3. `i=0`, `i<=3` (`2<=3` true) lets continue and increment i after it to 3
4. `i=0`, `i<=3` (`3<=3` true) lets continue and increment i after it to 4
5. `i=0`, `i<=3` (`4<=3` false) lets stop

so as you see loop iterated `4` times because there are 4 integer values starting from `0` which are *less **or equal*** to 3 (these values are 0, 1, 2, 3). To make it loop 3 times you need to remove one value from set of accepted integers, so either make it

- `1, 2, 3` by starting from `1` (`int i = 1`)
- `0, 1, 2` by not accepting `3` as valid argument in condition, so consider writing it as

  - `i<3` (used very often, you should get used to it)
  - or `i<=2`.